# Flutter:how to stream mysql database

Tags: flutter, firebase, sockets

I am trying to read database continuously but I am not finding any way to do it.First of all I am having a doubt that wether Firebase Realtime Database can do this task with out calling api multiple times.As per I researched over internet to accomplish my task I came to know that socket.io package or web sockets can Abel to complete task but I am trying to find the difference between Firebase Realtime Database and socket.io package which is the best approach to read data in database continuously.If I use socket.io package then how should I connect to my server and what is the procedure can any one explain with example

Comment: You need to show some code where you have tried to achieve what you are asking

Comment: I had not tried any code yet because I don't know where to start wether fire base or sockets I need clarity between these 2 to start

Comment: I use Firebase Realtime DB for the chat facility in my app (kinda what RTDB was designed for). It streams just fine. There are many places to find advice on how to do it, here is one: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage/.... I have no experience of using socket.io for this so can't advise which is best.

Comment: ok thank you waiting for some more sujesstions